# My custom Webpage for Oracle Cloud Application can be accessed from anywhere

Tags: web-deployment, weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-apps

I programmed (on JDeveloper Studio) a custom page for Oracle Cloud Application R13 and it is working like a charm. I deployed my customization on my Oracle WebLogic Server but I couldn't help to notice the website I created was HTTP and not HTTPS when I opened it from Oracle Cloud Application. On top of that, I also noticed I could access this custom webpage from anywhere (using any device) without any security verification or login as long as I use the same URL with its token.

**I would like to know how to make my custom webpage's url not being accesible just with its URL and also make it HTTPS instead of HTTP if possible.**

WebLogic Version: 12c

Oracle Fusion Application version: 11.13.18.10.0

JDeveloper version: 11.1.1.7.0

I believe this might have to do something with the WebLogic configuration, since I tested the same java project on Java Oracle Cloud SaaS Extension and it doesn't have this problem. Whenever I try to open that webpage from any other device, it asks me for login credentials. I am currently working with Oracle Java Cloud. (it is not the SaaS extension version) that's why I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured security for your application in JDeveloper?  If not then your page and application is considered public and not private.

As for HTTPS, weblogic server uses 2 ports one for HTTP and an other one for HTTPS.

Regards

Comment: I don't think my application has security. I didn't know that my applicaion would be public if I didn't code security in it. But it's weird since (as I said before) this same application was uploaded and deployed into another server with "Java Cloud Service SaaS extension" and it actually worked like it is supposed to (It asked the users for login registrations if the user didn't loged in previously). I did a little research. It may have something to do with my Weblogic URL being HTTP instead of HTTPS too. So for now. I'll try to make my WebLogic Server URL become HTTPS. Thanks for the reply.